# How to make .h files with class declaration while building .lib or .dll files?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have run into issues while using libraries and their dependencies.
I have following file tree configuration for learning how to deal with libraries in c++:

[image: Directory tree of solution]

where linked_list.lib and dll is generated from other project.
The project "Library" is generating another .lib file both static and dynamic and has class test with linked list as its member variable as:
test.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "Define.h"

#include "Linked_list/linked.h"

class TEST_API test {
    int i;

public:
    List<int> test_list;

    explicit test(int a);

    void set(int in);

    int get() const;

    void increment();

   void print() const;

};
```

the Macro TEST_API is defined in Define.h of source file of "Library" project
as:

```
#ifdef AN_BUILD_STATIC
    #define TEST_API
#else
    #ifdef AN_BUILD_SHARED
    #define TEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define TEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#endif
```

to properly set __declspec(dllimport) and (export) according to where it is included.

The include folder inside deps is from another project which has following Directory structure:

[image: Directory tree of Project producing Linked_list.lib]

This has Linked list declared in linked.h as:

```
#pragma once
#include "Define.h"
#include "node.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>


template <class T>
class LIST_API List {
private:
    node<T>* start;
    unsigned size;
public:
    List();

    explicit List(const T& input);

    void push(const T& data);

    T& operator[](const unsigned& index);
    const unsigned& getsize();

    void insert(const T& data,const unsigned& index);
};
```

Where `node.h` is just representation of each node in linked list and has all the implementation in same .h file and `Define.h` is also same as of previous one with define of `LIST_API`

**So my final question is:**

When I am using linked list in the `Library` project and compiling it it just builds fine but when I try to use the class `test` from Project `Library` in Project `Application` and hence have to include `test.h` I get error saying `Cannot open include file: 'Linked_list/linked.h'`.How can I solve this Problem?

PS: sorry for the long description but I didnot find any shorter way of explaining things..

**[Edit]**:

All the include paths in projects:
for Project `Library`:
`$(ProjectDir)src/include; $(ProjectDir)deps/include`

for Project `Linked_list`:
`$(ProjectDir)src\include\`

I didnot give any for `Application`
because its defined as:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include "../../Library/src/include/test.h"

int main() {
    test t1(40);
    t1.test_list.push(25);
    t1.test_list.push(5);
    t1.test_list.push(50);
    t1.test_list.push(250);
    for (int i = 0; i < t1.test_list.getsize(); i++) {
        std::cout << t1.test_list[i] << std::endl;
    }
    t1.print();
    t1.increment();
    t1.print();
    std::cout << "Hello World from normal file" << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

All the references, link Directories and link files are defined properly.

Comment: You have to provide the include paths: Go in Application properites -> C/C++ And add the path to Additional include directories

Comment: I had already done that.

Comment: @ankit Check `C++ -> Command Line` section in project properties. It should display actual additional include directories as `/I"..."` parameters. Make sure the expected directory is there and is correct and the expected header files are there (i.e. there should be subdirectory `Linked_list` with `linked.h` file there). Also project properties are different for different build configurations Debug/Relase Win32/x64. Make sure you have updated all the configurations you are using.